# iOS - iPhone / iPad Build Mini Apps (as features) inside 1 main App

Tags: iphone, ios, sybase, sup

I have a requirement to build **1 main App** that houses other mini apps as features.
Example, 1 main App called MY HR. Tapping on this, user will see icons like: 
Leave Approval, Pay Slip, Overtime Approval and etc.

**User authentication is shared** accross all the features, meaning to say, when user launch this 'Mega' app, he only needs to key in a PIN number once, then he can access all the other apps.

Each of this feature integrates with **SAP backend** using **Sybase Unwired Platform 2.1.3** technology.

Is there like a framework available, to build like a container app, that houses individual features, and it should be feasable whereby, in future, if I want to add Expense Approval, I can just do development and plug it in the main 'Mega' app easily.

This is similar to the **Hybrid Web Container** ios app made available by Sybase Inc, but that app houses mini HTML5 / CSS / Javascript apps and not mini ios native apps.

I have read couple of posts here before, some have suggested to add future apps by just adding more classes and xib files, but that would not be a best practise and be very messy. Besides, apple doesnt recommend this too.

What is your view on this requirement?

Comment: My advice is to not think of them as mini apps, but as separate views. That is all they are. You are over thinking the problem and looking for a "solution" that will cause you more pain than you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the Three20 project. More specifically, its launcher feature. http://three20.info/showcase/launcher

Comment: Hi Jordan, thank you for the response, yes we did opt for Three30 initially. But the client we are building this app for requirements an extreme tight secured environment, and they do not want to use any open source. They want to own the entire solution, and every bit of it should be custom. As such, Three30 was not in the picture. Any other similar non-open source technologies that could do this feature?